# opening PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

I'm new in iOS. I want to add PDF document in iOS. I try two options. URL and Document in iOS. But When I try open PDF with URL I get empty page. When I try with pdf document I get error on Xcode.

I try this for URL

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = rect.size;

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dokuman.osym.gov.tr/pdfdokuman/2012/OSYS/2012YGSSorular.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I try this one for document

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Is it about storyboard? Because I dont use .xib

I get this error.

2014-03-06 01:38:49.635 YGS[3934:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017395e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bc8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x0076eca5 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x0075f07e -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    4   UIKit                               0x0075f0f9 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014ce874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x0022c0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x0022c04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    8   UIKit                               0x003240c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    9   UIKit                               0x00324484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    10  UIKit                               0x00323733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    11  UIKit                               0x0059ec7f _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7166
    12  UIKit                               0x0026919a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    13  UIKit                               0x0026a0ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    14  UIKit                               0x0023de86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    15  UIKit                               0x0022818f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x016c283f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016c21cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016df29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016deac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016de8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x036de9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x036de809 GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x0022ad3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  YGS                                 0x0000305d main + 141
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d77701 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: I copy pasted your code, and it works fine for me. Did you make sure to `[self.view addSubview:webView]` ? And double check your internet connection. Also it's a 52 page document, so on a slow connection it might take a while to load.

Comment: Definitely share the error.

Comment: Waited 2 hours but It did not work. Is it about .storyboard? Because I dont use .xib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Ozgur it is to do with your storyboard - "'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

It tells you what the problem is - you are using a segue of type push which is trying to push a destination view controller when the source view controller is not a UINavigationController. Change the type of the segue or change the type of the source view controller, whichever is most appropriate for your GUI design.

Comment: So could you help me to which controller can I add or how can I add segue on storyboard?

Comment: You must have already added a segue otherwise how did you get one in the first place? To add a segue you drag and drop from the source view controller to the target view controller then a popup will appear asking you which type of segue you want. I can't tell you which type as I have no idea of the context and design of your program nor what type you yourself want for your GUI. I already said which type of controller - a navigation controller. I can't tell you if you need a navigation controller or not for the same reasons I have no idea what design you have or want in your application.

Comment: For now you could just try changing the type of the seque to modal to see if it works. Then you can decide how your storyboard needs to be designed to correspond to how you want your GUI to look and behave and  then if you need a navigation controller or not and which types of segues you need. You can delete the old segue and re-add a new one or change the type of an existing segue.

Comment: I wish I could TeamViewer you.. Yes I've been added ''webViewer'' segue but I can not find it on .storyboard. I watched videos and It was seems like only way to see that is .xib ''File Owner Sh*t''.

Comment: btw It is a very simple application. 'Single View'. It's like note pad. I've added sentences. One tab works for see sentences. Second tab  works for PDF. ( Not working but It will work someday:p)